# LT1389-5 voltage reference output is not as expected

Tags: power-supply, analog, voltage-regulator, power-electronics, voltage-reference

I am using the [LT1389-5](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1389fa.pdf) for one of my projects. My circuit is given below.

For 5 V output the maximum operating current is 10 mA. This is obtained from the maximum ratings.

I calculated the value of R1 based on a total current of 15 mA.

R1 = (12-5)/15 mA = 466 Ω.

When I simulated the circuit, I am getting an output voltage of 7.3 V.

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My input varies from 8V to 14V and I need 5V at the output. I swept the Vin from 8V to 14V.  What I can see is output is not a constant 5V.

Please see the waveform below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the datasheet it seems like whilst 10mA is the max current (i.e. current that the device can survive if exposed to), most of the accuracy specifications are based on having microamps of current flowing through the reference. This then results in a high impedance output which will droop as you apply 5mA of load at the output.

Comment: A different part or approach may be better for your design depending on how much voltage change you can tolerate on the 5V node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 10mA is an *absolute maximum* limit and you should be operating nowhere near there. Proper  operation is *not* implied or guaranteed.

The characteristics are only guaranteed up to 2mA for the 5V device. This is a nanopower part and not intended to sink large amounts of current, so not appropriate for a circuit such as yours. From the datasheet you linked:

[image]

If you do not require the high accuracy, fairly low drift (and low minimum operating current) of the rather excellent (at low currents) LT1389-5, a common TL431 and two resistors will function provided you give it a minimum of 1mA. It will sink 10mA or 15mA easily.

Here is the comparative behavior but with the currents in your circuit reduced by 10:1 (over an input range of 6 to 14V)

[image]

Now, include the trace for your circuit values:

[image]

According to the LTspice model it typically begins to lose regulation (with a typical sample, and at room temperature) at around 2.75mA.

Comment: Thank you.I updated the question.I am not getting a constant 5V for an input of 8V to 14V

Comment: Thank you,actully I need good refrence.In real circuit this 5V is used as reference voltage for our ebike throttle.

Comment: For an e-bike throttle I would think almost anything would be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Do not operate the part at Absolute Maximum Ratings. Those are damage ratings, not normal design operation characteristics.

There should never be 10mA (!) flowing through this device in reverse bias. There would have to be significantly more than the nominal 5V Vr voltage to get that much current to flow. If you check the datasheet page 8 "5V typical performance characteristics" graph "reverse characteristics", the reverse current knee is about at 600nA @ 5.0V.

Even though it's represented with a Zener diode symbol, it's a precision shunt voltage reference, not a Zener.

Page 10 shows some more typical operating circuits, where there is an op amp (LT1495 or similar) acting as an output current buffer.

(*Disclosure: although this isn't my product line, I am an Analog Devices applications engineer.*)

Comment: Thank you.I updated the question.I am not getting a constant 5V for an input of 8V to 14V